# How do I manually update my Nexus S to Jelly Bean?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, rom-flashing

I bought a used Nexus S that is on version 2.3.6.

It does not seem to be reading any SIM cards and the baseband version is listed as unknown. I think it may be on a custom ROM because of this. I want to flash it back to a stock ROM but have no idea where to start. My Nexus S is I9020A so I downloaded 4.1.1 from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#sojusjro03r) but have no idea where to go from here.

Are there any easy to follow guides? And am I even on the right track here?

Comment: I don't think there is such a model as "galaxy nexus S".  There's a "galaxy Nexus", and a "Nexus S".  I assume you have the latter, since the URL for its official image is almost the same as what you mentioned: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/soju-jro03e-factory-c9f5a67d.tgz

Comment: It looks like [this][1] might explain how to do it.


  [1]: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/doing-a-clean-install-of-android-on-nexus-s-galaxy-nexus-or-nexus-7

Comment: It sounds like your phone is missing the modem. I accidentally did the same thing once while updating a phone. You can just find the best modem for your area and flash it to fix this.

Comment: Did you notice that the link you provided points to a Nexus S 4G model, which is not the same as I9020a? The correct firmware would be [sojuajro03e](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#sojuajro03e)