# Android 4.2 Nexus 7 Update "Assert failed: apply_patch_check()"

Tags: updates

When I try to update my Nexus 7 from 4.1 (Jelly Bean) to 4.2 (also Jelly Bean) it works fine up to a point where the little android (with the rotating shape) lays down and has a red warning triangle with an exclamation point. When I press the power and VolUp buttons simultaneously to see what went wrong, the log shows this:

```
Verifying current system
Assert failed: apply_patch_check("EMMC:/dev/block/platform/sdhci-
tegra.3/by-name/LNX:5013504:c48f8e86e73fb2c2ba1794f5ec98e27c9e206ed5:
5060608:319331fae14fec8a88063751475fce26bae328e0")
```

I searched for the error message online and couldn't find anyone with the same problem. I even removed the random letters and numbers after "by-name" (I assume these are device-specific), and still found nothing. I also tried factory resetting and still the same problem.

I'd like to know what went wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: Why did you remove the random letters and numbers? They are part of a signature check to verify the update... probably the download got corrupted, was this OTA update? If so, you may have to re-initiate the OTA download again and retry.

Comment: I have downloaded and redownloaded probably 20 times. The update probably isn't being corrupted OTA.

Comment: disregard my last comment - something is wrong with the boot partition! Check the first posting over on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1742416) Notice that the block device name refers to the `/boot` partition... So my question to you is this, is the bootloader unlocked?

Comment: The bootloader was locked up until about 2 minutes ago. I'm going to try installing 4.2.1 with fastboot and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Good luck :) Please do report back your findings :)

Comment: I'll do that. Currently downloading the official 4.2.1 from Google.

Comment: It worked! My Nexus 7 successfully updated to 4.2.1. I used the instructions provided here: android.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/doing-a-clean-install-of-android-on-nexus-s-galaxy-nexus-or-nexus-7.

Comment: Congratulations! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what caused this problem. I had to unlock the bootloader and sideload with adb. This involved completely wiping my tablet. Here are [instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/doing-a-clean-install-of-android-on-a-nexus-phone-or-tablet). Now my tablet updates just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Q- What is an assert script?

A- All it does is check to make sure you are flashing the ROM on the correct device.

How to fix Android Custom ROM Status 7 installation Abort assert failed error in Recovery Easily [Ultimate Guide]:
http://mobotechie.com/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-android-custom-rom-status-7-installation-abort-assert-failed-error-in-recovery-easily-ultimate-guide

Assert failed [SOLVED]:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/optimus-v-rooting-roms-hacks/182438-solved-assert-failed.html

Thanks for those cool guys, and good luck.