# Update First Gen Nexus 7 to 4.3

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7

I have a first generation Nexus 7. It was getting so slow as to be useless, so I did a factory reset and it is not much better. It then informs me that an upgrade to Android 4.3 is ready. So I do that, but it doesn't seem to take because a day or two later, it informs me again that an upgrade to 4.3 is ready. I look and I see that the current version is 4.2.2. What is wrong?

Don't know if this matters, but before the reset, it was rooted, and so after I assume it is not and that's fine.

Comment: Factory resetting doesn't unroot your device, and being rooted is more than likely preventing the OTA from applying. You'll probably need to unroot or perform some kind of manual installation (a full reflash or a modified OTA designed to work on a rooted device). [Doing a clean install of Android on a Nexus phone or tablet](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/doing-a-clean-install-of-android-on-a-nexus-phone-or-tablet?rq=1) describes how to install a clean factory image.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well I'm fine with 4.2.2 so I'll just leave it. Thanks.